# Oracle weblogic 14..1.1.0 (14c) server opens on localhost instead of IP address

Tags: weblogic, weblogic14c

I've installed Oracle Weblogic in a oracle linux 8.5 VM and created a domain with following commands:

```
readTemplate('/u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver/common/templates/wls/wls.jar')
cd ('Server/AdminServer')
set('ListenAddress','')
set('ListenPort',7001)
create('AdminServer','SSL')
cd('SSL/AdminServer')
set('Enabled','True')
set('ListenPort', 7002)
cd ('/')
cd('Security/base_domain/User/oracle’)
cmo.setPassword('welcome123')
setOption('OverwriteDomain','true')
writeDomain('/u01/app/oracle/config/domains/APEX_DOMAIN')
closeTemplate()
exit ()
```

Weblogic server admin console opens up in browser on localhost:7001/console but does not open up on the VM IP address.

**How to fix this issue to open the weblogic admin console on the IP address?**

Thanks.

I tried setting the ***listener address as 0.0.0.0*** and restarted the server. Still the same.
Later I changed the ***listener address to 192.168.XXX.XXX*** and restarted the server. Now, console is not opening up on both (localhost and IP). It says ***Service weblogic.server.ServerLifeCycleService was started at level 9 but it has a run level of 10.***

Comment: This is resolved. I stopped the server, killed all the weblogic services and restarted the VM. Now I can access the weblogic UI on browser outside the VM.